# What is faster, Regex or if compares - Java

Tags: java, regex, performance, if-statement

I have two possibilities, make a regex or make a if compare.

If Compares

```
if (!(modoImpressao.equals("IMPRESSORA") || 
   modoImpressao.equals("PDF") || modoImpressao.equals("AMBOS")))
```

Regex Match

```
if (!Pattern.compile("(IMPRESSORA)|(PDF)|(AMBOS)",Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(modoImpressao).find()){
            throw new EspdNeverStopParametroInvalidoException(TspdConstMessages.IMPRIMIR_PARAMETRO_MODOIMPRESSAO_INVALIDO,"TspdImprimirNFCe");
        }
```

which one is faster?

Comment: Your DOTALL option is useless.

Comment: Normal String comparison/index Of, ... is always faster than regex. Use regex when you have a pattern.

Comment: Make a short program running each a few times on a loop, and find out for sure, instead of relying on speculation.

Comment: There are two problems with the code: (A) The two code snippets are semantically different as the first checks for string *equality*, while the second checks whether the subject string *contains* the pattern. Then (B) the regex contains the three unnecessary parenthesis paird, which pose a (small) performance hit, because they declare „capturing groups“.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first snippet will almost certainly be faster, since it doesn't have to parse a regular expression and perform a match against it. Another alternative is:

```
if (Arrays.asList("IMPRESSORA", "PDF", "AMBOS").contains(modoImpressao)
```

which shouldn't differ speed-wise much from your first snippet, but is arguably more readable and concise.

Regular expressions are great, but only use them when you *need* to. This situation definitely doesn't warrant the use of regexes; all you're doing is comparing against literal strings.

There's an old saying by Jamie Zawinski that goes like this:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Nice! But the alternative use `contains` not `equals`. And the time to parse the regular expression can be ignored and some cases, because it can be `static`. Your answer is good but not really answer some common questions arount this subject.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the regular expression only one time, it’s likely to be slower, especially when you use `find` where you actually mean `matches` as in your question.

When you keep the compiled `Pattern` and use it several times, it has the potential to be faster than multiple equals.

This, however, depends on the context. If all `String`s you are testing are literals and matches are more likely than fails, `String.equals` will be much faster as it circuits the test if the instances are the same.

---

The fastest solution is to preselect based on an easy-to-check property of the candidate `String`s which is different for all `String`s, e.g. a `char` at a certain position or the `length`, and perform a single `equals` for the selected `String`. In your case both, the first character and the length are appropriate. In this case I prefer length as you have to check the length anyway before accessing a character to protect against empty `Strings`:

The preferred variant using `length`:

```
nomatch:
{
  switch(modoImpressao.length())
  {
    case 3: if(modoImpressao.equals("PDF")) break nomatch; break;
    case 5: if(modoImpressao.equals("AMBOS")) break nomatch; break;
    case 10: if(modoImpressao.equals("IMPRESSORA")) break nomatch; break;
  }
  throw new EspdNeverStopParametroInvalidoException(
    TspdConstMessages.IMPRIMIR_PARAMETRO_MODOIMPRESSAO_INVALIDO,
    "TspdImprimirNFCe");
}
// one of the three values matched
```

The variant using the first `char`:

```
nomatch:
{
  if(modoImpressao.length()>0) switch(modoImpressao.charAt(0))
  {
    case 'P': if(modoImpressao.equals("PDF")) break nomatch; break;
    case 'A': if(modoImpressao.equals("AMBOS")) break nomatch; break;
    case 'I': if(modoImpressao.equals("IMPRESSORA")) break nomatch; break;
  }
  throw new EspdNeverStopParametroInvalidoException(TspdConstMessages.IMPRIMIR_PARAMETRO_MODOIMPRESSAO_INVALIDO,"TspdImprimirNFCe");
}
// one of the three values matched
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex is faster for large string than an if (perhaps in a for loops) to check if anything matches your requirement.

If you are using regex as to match very small text and small pattern and don't do it because the matcher function .find() is slower than a normal if statement of a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Java 7, you can use „string switches“, which are superfast because they’re based on the string’s hashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *find* pattern strings, rather than checking for *equality* (like your second code snippet does), performance may benefit from advanced string finding algorithms like Boyer-Moore-Horspool. While not trivial to implement on your own, many regex libraries (including java.util.regex) have it built in, so the search with the regex may be (much) faster in this case.

If „find()” speed is your major concern, you may also look into github.com/aunkrig/lfr .